# Warning: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file images/homepage. for dynamic images

Tags: jsf, primefaces, warnings, mime-types

My application is supports 4 languages.For example; if selected language is English, English icon is used on the home page

[image: project explorer]

I included images in a CSS like this;

```css
#cmlLogo {
    background:url("#resource['images/homepage/'.concat(fUserController.userLanguageCode()).concat('/kml_logo.png')]}") no-repeat  !important;
    width: 203px;
    height:127px;       
    background-position: right !important;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    background-size: auto !important; 
}
```

It is working but gives warning

> Warning:   JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file images/homepage.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.

How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: Do not use [java] tag as long as problem is not reproducible/demonstratable using a Java application class with `main()` method. This is a [jsf] specific problem.